# Select Rows from 1 table with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to select rows from my table where I look at the DocumentNo and Description, and if the Description repeats, it gets neglected / tossed / looked over. This is in MS Access, but can switch to DBeaver if necessary.

My table is of the sort

```
DocumentNo      Description
SSPT284886      Tongs
SSPT284894      Kit
SSPT284894      Tongs
SSPT284895      Tubing
SSPT284895      Tubing
SSPT284895      Countertop
```

In this case, my query should return everything except the 5th line.

I've tried

```
Select *
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.DocumentNo <> Table1.DocumentNo AND Table1.Description <> Table1.Description;
```

But this yields nothing, as I assume it looks for values that aren't equal to itself, essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct DocumentNo, Description
from table1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to select distinct on only two columns, but select everything else? Wait, it looks like it does that anyways. Today I learned...